# What would I need to do if my travel documents are lost in a natural disaster?

Tags: visas, passports, lost-documents, natural-disasters

Just thought about it,imagine i was at foreign country like usa,france,or any countries  etc ,i was stuck at natural calamity lets say flood,my passport & visa gets washed away,what would happen to my passport & visa in the above mentioned situation

would the foreign country issue a new passport & visa?

i need to contact my home country to issue the passport/visa?

Comment: I'd guess that you'd need to have the passport re-issued by the country who originally issued your passport, and the visa replaced/re-issued by the country who originally issued the visa. They're unlikely to be the same.

Comment: There is a procedure that kicks in both with your country and the host country.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple: you will need to contact your home country's embassy/consulate in the country you are staying at, and they will issue you a travel document to be used to pass to your country.

The country in which you are staying can not issue you a passport (unless you are a refugee or stateless or something like that), when the passport is lost, the maximum the host country can do is issuing some sort of a report via a police station stating that you have lose your passport. The rest has to be done via the consulate/embassy.

For the visa, you will need to issue a new one. Unless the visa is not attached to the passport and it is in a separate card or so. You also most likely will have to re-issue it from your country as most consulates will issue you a single use travel document (in case you needed to get back quickly), this can not be used to issue visas. In case your consulate issued you a full passport, not much countries will issue you a visa while you are in the country, you will need to get back. Unless it is a long term visa, things tend to be different in these cases.

Comment: While the physical passport and visa stamp/sticker **are** important, remember that all this information is stored in various government databases. Your own government for the passport, so they can issue a replacement, and the host government for the visa. They won't like the effort to look it up and to re-establish your identity, but they can do it.

Comment: @o.m. there will be no problem when leaving the country, they can look it up. The problem usually happens if you are in a country where they have checkpoints or police usually check identities.

Comment: Yes, get a replacement passport from *your* embassy and and a replacment visa from the *host* government.